# Вызов методов в Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#

Я правильно понимаю? Сначала вызывается метод ToDouble(), а потом уже результат вычисления в ToString() и вывод строки на консоль? т.е он неявно преобразовал его в Double?
[image: Код]

Comment: Да, зачем вам это?

Comment: Здесь принято код вставлять текстом. Если так важен скриншот, вы можете вставить его дополнительно, но не вместо кода.

Answer (score 4):

Если при умножении одно из чисел не целого вида, то при умножении будет возвращаться Double

Comment: В аргументе Console.WriteLine() , как я понимаю, да. Просто я думал нужно всегда явно указывать переопределение в Console.WriteLine((double)a*2.5), оказывается он сам неявно его переопределяет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: В C# Можно создавать методы с одинаковыми названиями, но с разными входными данными, пример: 
string sl(string f, string s) => f + s;
string sl(int f, int s) => f.ToString() + s;
Причём эти методы могут храниться в одном классе